# When i tap on a nativescript-local-notifications it launch the app but the addOnMessageReceivedCallback do not work

Tags: notifications, nativescript, localnotification, nativescript-vue

I have this

```
                            `LocalNotifications.addOnMessageReceivedCallback(
                            function (notification) {
                            console.log("ID: " + notification.id);
                            console.log("Title: " + notification.title);
                           console.log("Body: " + notification.body);
                            }
                             ).then(
                                function() {
                                  console.log("Listener added");
                                     }
                                     )
```

And when i tap on a local notification i do not get any output, it launch the app but the LocalNotifications.addOnMessageReceivedCallback do not seem to work at all. What can the problem be and how do i solve it ?

Comment: Is it iOS or Android? Which version you of OS you are testing it with?

Comment: @Manoj it is on iOS 13.1.3 and on a real device. I have absolutely no idea why it is not working.. i have the code i showed you almost highest up in main.js, but when i tap on a notification the addOnMessageReceivedCallback is not triggered